# Initial context factory value in Jmeter for MQ test plan

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq, performance-testing

I'm wanting to create test load onto a Websphere MQ queue using JMeter. I'm only wanting to place a message onto a queue - so I'm using the JMS Publisher sampler.
The config items I have are: MQHost:Port, MQChannel, MQQueueManager, MQQueue

In the sample, I've entered in some of the settings:
Provider URL: tcp://MQHost:Port
Destination: MQQueue

For the MQChannel and MQQueueManager I've added them into the JMS properties seetings:

Name: WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER , Value: MQQueueManager, Class of value: java.lang.String
Name: WMQ_CHANNEL, Value: MQChannel, Class of value: java.lang.String

I've got Connection Factory set as: MQConnectionFactory

Now the issue I'm racking my brains with is the Initial Context Factory setting. I'm stumped as to what package/class this should be set to.

The other option is to create a jndi.properties file with the MQ connection settings, but unclear as to how to do this either.

[image: JMeter JMS Publisher Sampler]

Thank you.

Comment: I spent far too long on trying to create a MQ performance test using this approach, and instead went about the approach using JMS administered objects and accessing via File system JDNI. 

I found information on these links helpful: 
- http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.co.nz/2014/07/jmeter-and-websphere-mq-series.html?_sm_au_=iVV5P5vR626sDt7V
- http://shekup.blogspot.co.nz/2009/06/oc4j-mq-series-adaptor-with-mdb-30-as.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm) it should be

```
com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
```

Also looking into your test plan you seem to be using incorrect syntax for [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), i.e. you should be using `${MQHost}` instead of `MQHost`.

Remember that JMeter doesn't come with any MQ jars, you need to get them somewhere somehow and drop to JMeter's CLASSPATH (usually "lib" folder of your JMeter installation, however it's configurable)

See [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for extended information and end-to-end instructions.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for the info - I couldn't find the .jar library that I needed that contained that initial context class. 
Yes you were correct about having the wrong JMeter variables - I had just used those as placeholder values for the screenshot.

I couldn't find a solution to my problem using this approach, but I did manage with another approach using JMS administered objects to store the MQ connection config in a File system JDNI namespace.